# How to set mplayer to start in the secondary display ? (.conf)

Tags: osx-lion, mplayer

I'm using mplayerosx-builds for video playback. How can I set mplayer to start in the secondary screen by default (using the .mplayer/.config file)?

OS: Lion 10.7.4